# Launch Rhythmbox using a Keyboard shorcut

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, rhythmbox, shortcut-keys

I use `Rhythmbox` all the time in my Ubuntu. Is it possible to have a custom shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Ubuntu, which can launch the Rhythmbox window, even if it is playing in the background ? Since, the emphasis of Linux OS flavors is to use keyboards as much as possible instead of mouse, i thought this functionality might tremendously help me in my Ubuntu environment.

The Keyboard shortcuts sections asks for a command; So, I'm not able to figure out how to give a custom keyboard shortcut to a program like `Rhythmbox`. I'm using `12.04` if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and click "Add"
As name type something you like, as command type "rhythmbox" and hit "Apply"
Then click on the right side of the new command where you can set the key combination and press Ctrl + R (or whatever shortcut suits you)

Comment: hi. I tried the keyboard shortcuts option. But it does not have any option to set a shortcut key. All it asks for is a Name and a command. I gave `rhythmbox` in the command and the same in the name. I couldn't find a place where keyboard shortcut can be given.

Comment: it works ! i missed the part when it says 'new accelerator' before pressing the new combination.

Answer (score 1):

You could install xbindkeys-config (which provides a fancy GUI) (`sudo apt-get install xbindkeys-config`), run xbindkeys-config, and put rhythmbox as the action, hit Get Key, press your key sequence, Save & Apply & Exit.

I personally find the control panel thing quite unreliable, compared to xbindkeys.

Comment: hi. i tried your method. But, `xbindkeys-config` crashes when I press keys button. Any idea on why this happens ? Is rhythmbox not allowed to have a keyboard shortcut ? And I'm seeing the following error in the console `Error : /home/arun/.xbindkeysrc not found or reading not allowed.
please, create one with 'xbindkeys --defaults > /home/arun/.xbindkeysrc'.
or, if you want scheme configuration style,
with 'xbindkeys --defaults-guile > /home/arun/.xbindkeysrc.scm'.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`